why no data available in my exploration for Views by Pages and Countries
I created Exploration for Views by Pages and Countries in google analytics 4, but cannot see data with message 'no data available'. Predefined reports for 'Pages paths and screens' and 'Active users by Countries' has data.
Why data is not available in that exporation?


No dimension was selected to be displayed in the report, it was only selected from a list but was not used. Double-click on the dimensions and metrics or drag and drop them where highlighted below:

